# Run a loop in bash with timeout in a single line

Tags: timeout, sh

I need to have a single line command that does something in a loop with a timeout.

Something like

```
export TIMEOUT=60
export BLOCK_SIZE=65536
COMMAND="timeout TIMEOUT while true; do dd if=/tmp/nfsometer_trace/mnt/TESTFILE of=/dev/null bs=BLOCK_SIZE; done"
```

The command will be executed in 'sh' by doing the following:

```
echo $COMMAND > COMMAND_FILE
sh COMMAND_FILE
```

But this gives me a syntax error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Is there any way to have a single line command to timeout an infinite loop?

Comment: your wrapper of `COMMAND="timeout ....` implies another layer beyond the shell. You'll need to include where your constructing this (PHP?, ruby, a zillion other softwares) OR how you expect to use `$COMMAND` later on? Consider editing your question (NOT A comment), to include output of `echo SHELL=$SHELL, BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION` or if you know you're using `ksh` please add `echo KSH_VER=${.sh.version}`. Good luck.

Comment: you may just be missing that TIMEOUT should be a variable value, ie `export TIMEOUT=60; COMMAND="timeout $TIMEOUT ...`. Good luck.

Comment: The TIMEOUT is just a placeholder I used for the example. It can be any number value.

Comment: Will cause less confusion if you show your actual code (as you have now done, (I think) ).  You'll still need to use `$TIMEOUT` in your real code, (or explain your wrapper process that I have hypothesized ; -) )  Same for `$BLOCK_SIZE`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command like

```
 while true ; do echo $(( i++ )) ; sleep 5 ; done
```

will produce output like

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
```

But if I try to use that command directly in timeout, I get similar error messages, i.e.

```
timeout 20 while true ; do echo $(( i++ )) ; sleep 5 ; done

 bash: syntax error near unexpected token do
```

Some programs (ssh for example), will process long strings of logic, if quoted so  the argument is all one string.

```
timeout 20 "while true ; do echo $(( i++ )) ; sleep 5 ; done"

timeout: failed to run command 'while true ; do ...'
```

same error msg whether I use single of dbl-quotes to pass in string.

Reading `info timeout` we see that

```
 COMMAND must not be a special built-in utility (*note Special built in utilities::).
```

Maybe `while` loops qualify as special built-in utility?

Finally, note that I have removed worrying about does using the "wrapper" information you have, ie.

```
export TIMEOUT=60
export BLOCK_SIZE=65536
COMMAND="timeout TIMEOUT while ....
```

as an cause of your problem.

When you have a problem like this, it is better to prove to yourself that your command is working in a simpler case and *then* get it work inside a more complex usage.

Given this evidence, I don't think timeout is designed to do what you want.

As a last resort, I recommend that you try converting that `while` loop into a script and calling just

```
 timeout 20 myLooperScript
```

IHTH

Comment: you do need to quote the complex command, but also passit to another shell as an argument: `timeout 20 bash -c "while true ; do echo $(( i++ )) ; sleep 5 ; done"`

Comment: @Amnon : Ah. very good, I'm aware of `bash -c`, but I used it very seldomly in my work. Thanks for the idea. I'll update my answer. . . . .

Comment: @Akshya11235 : See Ammon 's idea for fixing your `timeout looper` problem. Good luck to all.

Comment: @Amnon - it seems that your command print ` 0 0 0 0 `

Comment: @soninob , yep I confirm `0 0 0 0 0` output, Oops, I didn't test Amnon's idea, and cheerfully recommended it. My Bad!. Also, reviewing the whole thread, I should have commented at the time that `bash -c` is essentially the same as my advice to "convert(ing) that while loop into a script and calling just `timeout 20 myLooperScript`". That solution **does work**, I just tested it ;-) ! Thanks for your comments! Good luck to all!